# VS2019 - Android - Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException:

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I'm seeking your help regarding a strange problem that occurs only in Visual Studio 2019 but not in Visual Studio 2017.

We have a separate Android class Library project which contains Layout (.axml format). This will result in a Resource.Designer.cs at the end.

Use Case #1
- Visual Studio 2017
- Application launch without a problem :)

Use Case #2
- Visual Studio 2019
- Application crashes with the message **Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Resource ID #0x7f09001b'**

We tried to upgrade Xamarin Support Library to v28, change the AndroidManifest in case this issue was related to minSdkVersion/maxSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion but nothing worked :(

Comment: I create a android class library and create layout folder in Resources folder, then add layout.axml. I add this android class library as reference in android app, I do this test in visual studio 2017 and 2019, but I don't have any issue , so if you still have this issue, please provide you sample in github, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide you a sample because it's a project for a company :p But here's a link which is similar to our problem : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/563780/xamarin-android-resource-ids-mismatch.html?childToView=770719#comment-770719

The issue is old but was closed because the Support Team didn't receive sufficient votes from community

Comment: ,you can try to delete code from Resource.designer.cs file, then try to rebuild again, if it still crash, I think it may be the bug of Visual studio 2019.